# Define Strings in lang.h and use them in WM_PAINT?

Tags: c++

I am trying to teach myself C++ and have ran into a snag. This is my first attempt at making a simple connect to database Win32 program.

**What I want to do:**

I want all my strings defined in lang.h (this would allow for easier translating).

I then want to use `DrawText()` in the WM_PAINT case statement to draw the text in certain positions on the screen.

---

I have gotten the text to draw on the screen with this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

        SelectObject(ps.hdc, GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(ps.hdc, 100, 100, 500, 300);


        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        SetTextColor(ps.hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        SetBkMode(ps.hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        rect.left = 110;
        rect.top = 110;
        LPCWSTR message = L"Connect to Database: ";
        DrawText(ps.hdc, message, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);


        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
break;
```

But, what I really want to do is use the strings that I defined in lang.h

Example: (this does not work, just one of the many things I tried)

```
//lang.h
#define MSG_DBPATH = L"Path to Database:";

//SimpleDBConnect.cpp
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

            SelectObject(ps.hdc, GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
            Rectangle(ps.hdc, 100, 100, 500, 300);


            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            SetTextColor(ps.hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetBkMode(ps.hdc, TRANSPARENT);
            rect.left = 110;
            rect.top = 110;
            DrawText(ps.hdc, MSG_DBPATH, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);


            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
            break;
```

Is it possible to draw text on the screen within the WM_PAINT case statement using defined text in an external header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MSG_DBPATH L"Path to Database:"
```

Note no equal sign and no semicolon.

Comment: oh man, I have tried sooooo many different things and spent a few hours looking stuff up. You have it solved in probably 30 seconds... lol, thanks a bunch, it works!